# QOpenGLWidget in QTabWidget slows MouseMoveEvent

Tags: qt, opengl, qopenglwidget

For a kind of CAD application I first create a QWidget (intended as a 2D editor) with mouse tracking enabled in a tab of QTabWidget. Drawing and moving lines is super fast as expected.

Next I create a new tab with an QOpenGLWidget (intended as a 3D view). No mouse tracking, but it reacts super fast to mouseMoveEvent() when button pressed. As expected.

Now when I switch the tab back to the QWidget mouseMoveEvents become very slow. WHY? Switching back to GL shows that the QOpenGLWidget still reacts fast.

I inserted QDebug output to paintGL() - it's not called. Next I uncommented all of the code in initializeGL(), resizeGL() and paintGL(), so no GL code at all remains. Still the same problem!

Qt version is 5.5.1 running on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

Comment: When user change tab - try set programmatically focus, focusPolicy, mouseTracking and other similar props between this widgets (disable for invisible and enable for curent visible widget). And/or try place your widgets into simple tab-widgets (as wrappers only) and change props for your widgets (not for wrappers).

Comment: I tried all that - no success. Event wrapped the GL widget and called deleteLater() in hideEvent() - still stays slow. Same when it has never even been shown. And it has nothing to do with the QTabWidget; same effect when I place it on top level. THIS HELPS: I created a **new QMainWindow**, place the GL widget inside it, and resize and show the new main window! Hmm, maybe a multi-window GUI is what I always wanted?!